# Deal array values to a single field of a structure array (in Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I thought `deal` should do it but it does not, and I cannot find another nice solution.

I have an array `a = 1:2`. I would like to put the values 1 and 2 into a structure array `b` like so:

```
b(1).a = 1
b(2).a = 2
```

To my surprise, `[b(1:2).a] = deal(1:2)` does not deal the values, but puts the vector `[1 2]` into each field `a` of structure `b`:

```
>> b(1)
ans = 
    a: [1 2]

>> b(2)
ans = 
    a: [1 2]
```

Am I missing something with syntax here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deal` does what it is expected to do. It distributes the input arguments among the outputs, and if it has only one argument (the vector `1:2`) it replicates it as many times as the number of output arguments. You were probably looking for:

```
[b(1:2).a] = deal(1, 2); %// or simply [b.a] = deal(1, 2)
```

In the general case, you'll probably have to create a cell array from your values (*e.g* using [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html)) and use a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), for instance:

```
C = num2cell(v);         %// v stores the values
[b.a] = deal(C{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the hint of Eitan, you may want this

```
b = struct('a',num2cell(a));
```